# Change the position of h1 randomly using a button

Tags: html, button, position

I have to change the position of a title `h1` randomly after pressing a button.

Here is my code:

Declaration of HTML

```js
function move() {
  console.log("MOVE");
  var text = document.getElementById("text_to_move");
  text.style.positon = "absolute";
  text.style.left = randomposition();
  text.style.top = randomposition();

}

function randomposition() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) // RANDOM NUMBER BETWEEN 0 AND 100
  var y = x + "px";
  console.log(y);
  return y;

}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <h1 id="text_to_move">
    TITLE
  </h1>
</header>
<input type="button" value="MOVE" onclick="move()">
```

¿Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `position:relative` to id **#text_to_move**:

Here is the updated code snippet:

```js
function move() {
  console.log("MOVE");
  var text = document.getElementById("text_to_move");
  text.style.positon = "absolute";
  text.style.left = randomposition();
  text.style.top = randomposition();

}

function randomposition() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) // RANDOM NUMBER BETWEEN 0 AND 100
  var y = x + "px";
  console.log(y);
  return y;

}
```

```css
#text_to_move{
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <h1 id="text_to_move">
    TITLE
  </h1>
</header>
<input type="button" value="MOVE" onclick="move()">
```

Comment: It works! But why it dosn't work if I put  text.style.positon = "relative"; instead of adding css code?

Comment: it should work. might be some error please accept this answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Yes. I'm going to accept it, but i need to wait 10 minutes after my question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function move() {
  console.log("MOVE");
  var text = document.getElementById("text_to_move");
  text.style.left = randomposition();
  text.style.top = randomposition();
  text.style.position = "absolute";
}

function randomposition() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) // RANDOM NUMBER BETWEEN 0 AND 100
  var y = x + "px";
  console.log(y);
  return y;

}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <h1 id="text_to_move">
    TITLE
  </h1>
</header>
<input type="button" value="MOVE" onclick="move()">
```

you can still use position absolute. see my snipet
the main problem is you are a little typo in writing.

```
true (me)   = text.style.position = "absolute";
false (you) = text.style.positon = "absolute";
```